# How to find index of next similar letter in a string

Tags: python, string, substring

```
a = "programming in python is Fun"

a.find("i") = 8
```

It returns index of first occurrence of `"i"` in a.
Is it possible to find index of second `"i"`?

Comment: Yes, look into index method's behavior. https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`find()` takes an optional start index as well which you can use as:

```
a = "programming in python is Fun"
first = a.find('i')
print(a.find('i',first+1))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#enumerate) with [*list comprehension*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to find all the indexes as:

```
s = "programming in python is Fun"
my_char = "i"

my_indexes = [i for i, x in enumerate(s) if x == my_char]
# where `my_indexes` holds:
#    [8, 12, 22]
```

Here `my_char` is the character of which you want to find the index. And `my_indexes` is a list containing the indexes of each time `my_char` is found in the string. Please refer [`enumerate()` document](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#enumerate) for more details.

Hence, you can access index of second occurrence as:

```
>>> my_indexes[1]
12
```

Comment: that one is very cool. probably not as fast as ```.find()``` on paper, but the algo is better imho.

If I may, remove that ```, x in enumerate```, ```ì for i in s``` will do just fine, a string is just a list of chars.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `numpy` in the following way:

```
import numpy as np
a = "programming in python is Fun"
x = np.frombuffer(a.encode(), dtype=np.uint8)
np.where(x == ord('i')) # (array([ 8, 12, 22]),)
```

Using [`np.frombuffer`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.frombuffer.html) reinterpret str as a char buffer and then using [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) will return all the indices that will match the character you are interested in (or more accurately the integer representing the Unicode character, using [`ord`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/ord)).

Comment: isn't loading numpy a bit heavy for that task ?

Comment: @Loïc It might be overkill, but if you have a very long string I guess this will be the fast. Of course, I also wanted to give some other approach to the one given.